# PHP HTML FORM CHECKBOX value maximum - POST converts to GET

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

HTML FORM (POST) works fine for CHECKBOX parameters with VALUEs <= 1,073,741,824  (commas added *here* for readability)

however, with a checkbox CHECKED (and thus sent to the server) having a VALUE of  2,147,483,648
the METHOD changes to GET  even tho the FORM specifies POST

This usage is needed to represent values up to 2**64, and the HTML checkbox tags are programmatically generated based on current db content.

*Disambiguation: this is not about MAXLENGTH (character length)*
*Disambiguation: this is not about the NUMBER of checkbox options*

when i add the HTML5 max="4294967296"  (2**32, as a test)  it still does not work.

```
When i change the     value='2147483648'  parameter to a *char str*
    value='x2147483648'
it works as desired (viz., POST)
```

i've tried in CHROME & FIREFOX.

here's the bare bones HTML excerpt pared down to the 2 critical checkboxes present.

```
<form method="POST" action="example.com/xxx.php" >    
    <input type="checkbox" name="SeasonBits1"  value='1073741824'   >
    <label for="SeasonBits1">Option[1,073,741,824]</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="SeasonBits2"  value='2147483648'   >
    <label for="SeasonBits2">Option[2,147,483,648]</label> 

    <input name="Command" type="submit" id="Command2" value="UPDATE"  />
</form>

results when only Option[1..] is checked:
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [SeasonBits1] => 1073741824

results when only Option[2..] is checked:
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    (no $_POST  *OR*  $_GET array contents at all)
```

Please help me see what i'm missing w.r.t. checkbox integer value limitations.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your issue. You must be casting or doing something to your POST.

Comment: How are you handling it in `xxx.php` it works fine for me because it should be putting the value as a string not an integer. `array (size=3)
  'SeasonBits1' => string '1073741824' (length=10)
  'SeasonBits2' => string '2147483648' (length=10)
  'Command' => string 'UPDATE' (length=6)`

Comment: Try to see what is inside your post in `xxx.php` like this `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now explained.

mod_sec in the server firewall was catching large integer values in POSTs

"COMODO WAF: Looking for integer overflow attacks"

again many thanks for your responses which all helped to lead to this discovery

(this mod_sec rule is now whitelisted for this account)

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate what you describe using the following test page in Google Chrome ~ seems to work 100% OK. the form values were increased by `1`  but tested with original values prior to any changes - worked OK.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>POST changes to GET???</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' or !empty( $_REQUEST['SeasonBits1'] ) or!empty( $_REQUEST['SeasonBits2'] )){
                printf( "<pre>%s\n%s</pre>", print_r( $_POST, true ),$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] );
            }
        ?>
        <form method='POST'>    
            <input type='checkbox' name='SeasonBits1' value='1073741825'   >
            <label for='SeasonBits1'>Option[1,073,741,825]</label>
            <input type='checkbox' name='SeasonBits2' value='2147483649'   >
            <label for='SeasonBits2'>Option[2,147,483,649]</label> 
            <input name='Command' type='submit' id='Command2' value='UPDATE'  />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent help. based on your feedback, i have further tracked it down to .htaccess re-writing of the URL.   the  checkbox script is in a non-WP section of the website that is accessed directly via URL.   the  WP .htaccess rules don't like the specific value ending in 648.  Your ...649 works in my context, but 648 gets redirected, and thus loses the METHOD and presents as GET.    THANK YOU AGAIN for helping lead to resolving this odd sequence of dependencies